# DynamoDB - Export .csv file and filter some of the items (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to get a .csv file with the items from a DynamoDB that meet some specific conditions? For example I want the items that have a specific value for a specific attribute. I couldn't find anything specific.

Comment: The DynamoDB API is largely a DIY interface. Aside from using third party tools, you can also aggregate items into an array and dump into `fputcsv()` or similar.

Comment: did you check this link? - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html